# make RMI Stub with netBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi, sun, stub

I see some where in the web that we can make Stub dynamically with Netbeans and it`s a good feature of it.

I search a lot but all hits are from Old version (4 or 5) and others told a complete reference is in Netbeans website but the links is removed and i couldn`t find it in the site.

Broken Link : rmi.netbeans.org

Please if there is way which i don`t know tell me or there is not let me know for not search any more and try to work with rmic.

more search results :

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5037503
http://forums.netbeans.org/post-8076.html&highlight=

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 6 there is no need of creating stubs to run an RMI program and if you are using a older version here is the [solution](http://blogs.oracle.com/branajam/entry/rmi_and_netbeans).